# Cakephp 3.0 Unable to Update associated model

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

**UserMastersTable.php:**

```
$this->hasOne('PersonMasters', [
            'className' => 'PersonMasters',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_master_id',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function editUser($id) {

        $countryOptions = $this->Countries->find('list')->select(array('id', 'name'));

        $this->set(compact('countryOptions'));

        $user_detail = $this->UserMasters->get($id, ['contain' => ['PersonMasters']]);
        $this->set('user_detail', $user_detail);

      if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
        $user=$this->UserMasters->newEntity();

         $user = $this->UserMasters->patchEntity($user,$this->request->data,['associated'=>  ['PersonMasters']]);


            $this->UserMasters->save($user,['associated'=>  ['PersonMasters']]);

        }

    }
```

It will not update data. Each time a new record is saved in `user_masters` and `person_masters` table. So how to update data in both `user_masters` and `person_masters`?

I if set one hidden field in `.ctp` view file that contain `user_masters` `id` then it only updates `user_masters` record and new record is added in `person_masters` table.

I already assigned `' * '=true` in every entity, including `UserMasters`. Still it doesnt work. 
So how can I update `user_masters` and associated tables in cakephp3.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the question is that a new entity is created and patched, the posted data did not include primary key values, so it was always an insert.

The fix is to instead patch the `$user_detail` object (which already contains existing primary key values, since it's read out of the db) and then save that:

```
$user = $this->UserMasters->patchEntity(
    $user_detail, 
    $this->request->data, 
    ['associated' => ['PersonMasters']]
);
$this->UserMasters->save($user,['associated'=>  ['PersonMasters']]);
```